# Is there any protocol use the options header?

Tags: protocols, ipv4

Is there any protocol use the options header ?
I want to use options header to take some data while transfer, so I want to check if there any protocol use the options header. Or I will occupy the header.

Comment: i'm curious what you're wanting to do.  Piggyback some additional information with the packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are any number of protocols which might or could use IPv4 options.  None of them are in normal, common use.  I've certainly used record-route a time or two, and there are any number of RFCs describing usages and experiments.  http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip.htm#Options

There are no IPv6 options in the actual ipv6 header because of the "Next Header" functionality, which allows you to insert arbitrary headers in the packet.  So the record-route option I mentioned for IPv4 as a user of IPv4 options would be a header of its own.  Be sure to carefully read the document on the selection of the protocol number since that controls what happens when people parse the packet.

Comment: Hi, I want to know how about the options header in IPv6. Because there are no options header in IPv6.

Comment: @Jimmy: Answer edited, though your question is marked IPv4.  Be sure to accept my answer if it is useful.